# Laravel FirstOrCreate function with null value converts to string

Tags: laravel

I send a null value for search field, and it converts to string.
using laravel 8. php 7.4

```
$notification = Notification::firstOrCreate([
'resource' => $notif['resource'],
'topic' => $notif['topic'],
'response' => null
], [some other values]);

returns

#attributes: array:12 [
"resource" => "/item/55359"
"topic" => "item"
"response" => "null" --> like string and not null value
"status_id" => "Pending"
"attempts" => 0
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did it find a record or create a new one?

Comment: What does your `Notification` model look like?

Comment: Converting empty string to null is because of a middleware in laravel called `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` and you can find it in the middleware list of Http>Kernel.php. What is your challenge?

Comment: @lagbox it creates a new one every time

Comment: @James is something there i will investigate... i tried with an empty model and it saves a null value right.

Comment: is there a `response` key in the second array you are passing to `firstOrCreate`?

Answer (score 0):

thanks
it was a model problem...
the response field saves a json string.. and it was converting the null value to json string.

that was the problem.
i have add this line before

if (is_null($value)) $this->attributes['response'] = $value;

thanks all